# When connected to VPN using the built-in VPN service, is all my internet traffic routed through the VPN connection?

Tags: vpn

I have configured a VPN service using only the built-in options from OS X. I have configured it as follows:

- Interface: VPN
- VPN Type: Cisco IPSec
- Service name: ...

I don't have any settings under Advanced, so I have entered no DNS Servers, no Search Domains, and no Proxie Servers or Proxy Configuration file for any of the protocols.

When am I connected to this VPN, does all my traffic go through the VPN connection? In other words, if I am using a messenger, searching on Google, sending email or browse the web, can the provider of the VPN service see all my traffic?

Edit:

Here are the default entries in my routing table (output from `netstat -r -n`):

```
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           10        0     en1
default            gway#5             UCSI            0        0   utun0
```

There are a whole bunch of IP-addresses that list specific gateways. I checked some of those IP-addresses, and they are related to the network that I use the VPN for.

Does the fact that the first `default` is my own modem/router mean that in fact not all internet traffic passes through the VPN?

Answer (score -2):

Yup when using the VPN everything goes through your VPN.

Comment: I am not so sure, can you give a reference or further explanation to support your answer?
I edited my question by adding the routing table and some more info about it. Do you think it's that easy as simply yes, or do you think this extra information may actually indicate something else? The reason I ask is because I don't know enought about routing to know for sure.

Comment: That's not true, it depends by the VPN configuration.